# How to find all IIS applications/websites that not used anymore?

Tags: iis, asp.net

In our server, there are a lot of ASP.NET/IIS applications/websites created a long time ago. Now we need to find a way to mark all these applications/websites that are not used anymore(no hits for 1 week or 1 month). Is there is a way to figure this out?

Comment: IIS log files contain that information if you parse them in the right way (LogParser for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Retiring assets is not entirely a technical problem.

Find organizational owners that will advocate for sites continued existence out of your limited resources. Retire applications without owners slowly over time. With perhaps months between, notify users, shut down the app but leave it there, then take a final backup and delete it.

For a data driven decision, yes you can do analysis. Choose tools to parse web server request logs, and performance counters for connection counts and requests per second, and other logs. Try something, and ask a more specific question if you have problems with your query.